# Looking for taxonomy for skills databases?

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data, metadata

I am looking for taxonomy databases or datasets other than "O*Net" which can have skills (Tools and technologies). Added to the above, I am also looking for taxonomy which can have skills from pharma and medical fields.

I also need to identify skills in job description which describe the abilities, (For example , "good communication skills", "speak English and Spanish", "effectively communicate with customers"), is there any taxonomy by chance?

Answer (score 2):

Open Skills offers an API, though I'm not sure if the data matches your requirements:
[Open Skills Project](http://dataatwork.org/data/)